# "Местами" — вводное слово или нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Подскажите, пожалуйста, нужно ли обособлять "местами" в этом предложении (перефразировано, но суть такая же):

*Бокал своими() местами() резкими гранями пускает солнечных зайчиков.*

Меня не покидает ощущение, что запятая нужна, потому что без неё пришлось несколько раз перечитать, чтобы уловить смысл. С другой стороны, "местами" само по себе не вводное слово. Не смогла найти информацию в справочниках. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обособляются (отделяются запятой в начале и в конце предложения и выделяются с обеих сторон в середине предложения) слова и словосочетания, уточняющие смысл предшествующих слов, определения со значением цвета, размера, возраста...

*Ещё одно*, (какое именно?) *последнее, сказанье – и летопись окончена моя (Пушкин); Кой-где выглянули женские*, (какие именно?) *большей частью старушечьи, головы (Тургенев)*.

---

Они могут конкретизировать общее значение местоимений этот, такой, каждый, один (не в значении числительного, а в значении местоимения) и др.:

*Чичиков немного озадачился таким, (каким именно?) отчасти резким, определением (Гоголь)*.

1. Обособление уточняющих согласованных определений — явление достаточно редкое и во многом зависит от воли пишущего. Обычно определения с уточняющим значением рассматриваются как однородные, то есть запятая ставится не с двух сторон, а с одной — между определениями.

*Быстрыми шагами прошёл я длинную «площадь» кустов, взобрался на холм и... увидел совершенно другие, незнакомые мне места (Тургенев)*.

2. Уточняющие определения могут присоединяться посредством подчинительных союзов.

*Неодолимая, хотя и тихая, сила увлекла меня (Тургенев); Нельзя так убиваться из-за простого, пусть и такого дорогого, костюма (Савельев)*.

Но если определение, присоединяемое подчинительным союзом, является однородным по отношению к предшествующему и не носит характера уточнения (смыслового и интонационного!), то после него запятая не ставится.

*Получены важные, хотя и не итоговые сведения*.

https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724v

После первого абзаца можно было бы и остановиться, т. к. пример из него более всего отвечает теме вопроса.

Ответ: *Бокал своими, местами резкими, гранями пускает солнечных зайчиков*.

Comment: А ведь точно! мне все казалось, что что-то не так. Нужно было "местами резкими" рассматривать, а не одно слово. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: @Лиза Здесь не обязательно делать уточнение. Если уточнение, то и две паузы. Уточнение слова "своими" обычно делается, когда говорят о человеке. Стилистика под сомнением.

Answer (score 2):

Нет, это наречие и обстоятельство:
[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/местами](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Если вам интересно обособление таких обстоятельств, то вот:
[image]
Но здесь это не требуется. Паузы ни к чему.

Наверно, вы просто посчитали, что здесь не обстоятельство, а существительное "места". Но такое никогда не влияло на пунктуацию. На пунктуацию влияет, когда надо показать, к чему относится синтаксическая единица, а не какой частью речи является слово.

Comment: Вопрос: *своими местами*, вдруг если окажется в на конце строки, не надо ли разбить?

Comment: А когда конец строки на что-то влиял?

Comment: Там происходит много интересного.

Comment: Что, например, кроме ситуаций с числами?

Comment: Теряется нить смыслов из-за нелепых переносов слов и словосочетаний.

Comment: Теперь понял, что вы имеете в виду. Но нет же таких типографических правил.

Comment: О редакционном процессе и правке тома написаны. //// Цитирую автора вопроса: «*Меня не покидает ощущение, что запятая нужна, потому что без неё пришлось несколько раз перечитать, чтобы уловить смысл*».

Comment: Не думаю, что такое есть, потому что если слово большое, то при переносе текст строки сильно растянется.

Comment: А запятая обозначает паузу, это не указатель.

Comment: Спасибо за материал! Сохранила, чтобы в дальнейшем применять :)

Answer (score 2):

Лучше так: *Бокал, **своими резкими местами гранями,** пускает солнечных зайчиков.*

Это обстоятельство образа действия (как?), которое обособляется в силу **своей позиции и распространенности**. Без обособления предложение сложно прочитать:  в этом случае подлежащее и оборот должны произноситься  **в одну фразу.**

Обособление обстоятельств по правилам (Розенталя и ПАС) является **факультативным**.

[Розенталь:](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=115#pp115)  Могут обособляться (выделяться запятыми) обстоятельства, выраженные наречиями (одиночными или в сочетании с зависимыми словами), с целью **смыслового выделения или пояснения**: *Проснувшиеся грачи, **молча и в одиночку**, летали над землей (Ч );*

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Еще вариант правки с изменением падежа: *Бокал, **своими резкими в отдельных местах гранями**, .*

Или (**факультативное обособление**):

*Бокал своими резными гранями // пускает солнечных зайчиков.*

*Бокал, **своими резными гранями**, пускает солнечных зайчиков.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! я не имею право как-то менять текст. Хотя предложение и перефразировано, порядок слов остался таким же, как и у автора. Все сохранила, чтобы не забыть!

Comment: Предложение  при обособлении оборота выглядит стилистически  некорректно. Можно сказать: Бокал своими гранями пускает солнечных зайчиков. Но если добавить обособленный оборот, то оборот выглядит уточняющим, а это уже странно (местоимение "своими" как бы подчеркивается ударением, а потом уточняется; а зачем это делать?). А не обособлять нельзя. Вот и пришлось сделать перестановку.

Comment: У меня вообще никаких проблем нет, чтобы прочитать в одну фразу, и изначально понял, что то наречие. "*Резкими местами гранями*" — это плохо, звучит уже не плавно, да и можно подумать, что места резкие. В исходном варианте, чтобы правильно понять, надо видеть следующее слово — "резкими", не знаю, рассматривали ли такое лингвисты. Но пунктуация не для того, чтобы устранять такое.

Answer (score 0):

Я называю такие слова ‟наречия характеристики характеристики”, потому что они обозначают характеристику характеристики, которая обозначается или прилагательным, или наречием характеристики действия. Вот несколько примеров сочетаний с такими словами: морально устойчивый, абсолютно необходимые, безупречно порядочные, глубоко задумчивый, демонстративно небрежная, диаметрально противоположные, жизненно важное. Вот пример таких слов, когда они относятся к прилагательному и к наречию характеристики действия: необычайно быстрый человек, бежал необычайно быстро.

В вашем предложении слово ‟местами” является таким же наречием характеристики характеристики, и, конечно, от слова, которое следует за ним, отделяться запятой не может; ‟местами резкими” в данном случае – распространённое определение.

После ‟своими” запятая не ставится по правилу об отсутствии запятой между притяжательными местоимениями и другими однородными определениями, если однородное определение не является пояснением (в данном случае это не так). [(Ссылка на справочник Розенталя, пункт 4.)](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109)

В итоге: ‟Бокал своими местами резкими гранями пускает солнечных зайчиков.”

Comment: Я не вижу никаких малейших проблем у этого предложения. Оно такое же как, например: ‟Он привлекла меня своим необычайно выразительным лицом”.

Comment: Если вы придумали на ходу пунктуационную норму, а потом пытаетесь навязать её миру, то это ваша проблема, так как у вас это вряд ли получится. По сути, вы предлагаете убрать из употребления наречие ‟местами”, потому что оно произошло от существительного в творительном падеже и у кого-то возникнет затруднение с мгновенным восприятием этого слова как наречия. По этой логике, из языка придётся убрать много слов. Отвечать не будут.